# How to fix bar width in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

i'm starting new project using python and chart.js and i am using bar chart of chart.js, I want to fix width of every bars but it's still look like this, so how can i apply fix width for all bar?

Max 6 bar showing at a time, when we add 7th bar then horizontal scroll is appeared.[image]

Comment: You should include a code example of what you are trying to do as it will make it more clear as to what you need help with.

Comment: I am using Chart js, here is docs link for your reference.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: I mean of your own JavaScript and CSS

Comment: There are no CSS bcz it's canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use :

barPercentage property like this

```
xAxes:[{
     barPercentage: 0.1,
            gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }]
```

barPercentage  takes value from 0 to 1 where 1 being the 100% available width

For more details on barPercentage see [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options)

Sample [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/111/)

For fix width with different data variant :

Try this [link1](https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/118/) [link2](https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/119/)

Comment: Thanks, I have one question, Is that possible to apply fix width to each bar? no meter there was 10 bar or 100 bar. I just wanted to apply same width for all bars.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana I dindn't quite get you in the fiddle its still same width for all bars isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, But If I remove all data and apply just one data then that one bar is looking big, same as above screenshot. try it on fiddle.

Comment: Ah i see try using then barThickness property from docs that will solve your problem

Comment: try like this https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/115/ or https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/114/ both have same width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140063/discussion-between-kaushik-makwana-and-vinod-louis).

Answer (score 1):

## This fixes it

works for most versions, including in react.js

```
import {Chart} from "chart.js"

Chart.defaults.datasets.bar.barThickness = 73;

//also try barPercentage, maxBarThickness
```

Answer (score 1):

use this as example

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("my_chart").getContext("2d");

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Title on top",
            data: [10, 80, 56, 60],
            backgroundColor: "#1491e5",
            barThickness: 30 //<---- here important
        }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false//<---- here important
    }
});
```